# Javascript & partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

hi 
I have page which is action "create" for order.

I want to be able dynamically to add multiple boxes and submit all the items as one request.
I know how to add one a time and save as ajax request but not all at once
Any Ideas how to do that?

```
public class oder{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Recipient{get;set;}
public List<Box> Boxes{get;set;}
}

public class Box{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string
}
```

I have simplified the html code

```
<% html.SubmitForm(){ %>
<div><%: html.textboxfor(model=>model.Recipient) %></div>
<div class="Action">Add Box</div>

<fieldset>
<legend>Boxes</legend>

</fieldset>

<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful.